# How admin route in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

My folder structure is following:

```
Controller>admin>`loginController`
view>admin
model>admin
```

In LoginController includes authorization process

I have used routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
      Route::get('/', 'LoginController');
});
```

But i also found error 'Controller method not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to use [`Route::controller()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers) or specify the action that you want to route to. For example:

#### Controller

```
public function showLogin(){
   return View::make('login');
}
```

#### Route

```
Route::get('/', 'LoginController@showLogin');
```

(With the `@` part you tell Laravel what controller method you want to call)